# App version update check with play store without using any back-end server/web-service?

Tags: android, google-play, updates

How to check new update is available or not in the play store. Is there any simple way to obtain this.

**Limitations.**
  1. No custom web-service.

**Can use**

1. User agent.
2. Any API offered by google.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use firebase console

Comment: use firebase remoteconfig. https://firebase.google.com/remoteconfig

Answer (score 1):

Use this helper method to find updated version in play store

```
private String getPlayStoreVersion(){
    final String PLAY_STORE_URL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%s&hl=%s";
    final String PLAY_STORE_TAG_RELEASE = "itemprop=\"softwareVersion\">";
    String version = "0.0.0.0";

    Boolean isAvailable = false;
    String source = "";
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String formedString = String.format(PLAY_STORE_URL,"com.demo.application.yourapp",Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    ResponseBody body = null;
    try {

        URL playStoreURL = new URL(formedString);
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        body = response.body();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(body.byteStream(), "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(PLAY_STORE_TAG_RELEASE)) {
                str.append(line);
                isAvailable = true;
               }
        }
        response.body().close();
        source = str.toString();

        if (isAvailable) {
            String[] splitPlayStore = source.split(PLAY_STORE_TAG_RELEASE);
            if (splitPlayStore.length > 1) {
                splitPlayStore = splitPlayStore[1].split("(<)");
                version = splitPlayStore[0].trim();
            }
         }


        return version;

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return version;
}
```

**Note:Use in Background thread**

Comment: I will get back to you soon with any update on this. thnx

Answer (score 1):

So I think I have an easy solution to the problem.

Dependence required.

```
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
```

Sample Code

```
class GetVersionCode extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    private static final String currentVersion = "x.x.xx";
    static final String packageName = "com.xxx.xxx";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        String newVersion = null;
        try {
            newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName + "&hl=it")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get()
                    .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
                    .first()
                    .ownText();
            return newVersion;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // HTTP error fetching URL, 404
            return newVersion;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String onlineVersion) {
        super.onPostExecute(onlineVersion);

        if (null == onlineVersion) {
            // Some error occurred
            return;
        }

        if (onlineVersion.compareTo("") == 0) {
            // Some error occurred
            return;
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), onlineVersion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```